# Skipping empty indexes in a 2d char[][] array when looping the array for a char value and appending it to a String

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, stringbuilder

How do you skip all empty indexes in a 2D char[][] array when looping through it to build a string out of of all the indexes that do have a char value?

In the code below I used `\0` to represent the empty indexes and wrote a condition to append all indexes that are not `\0` to text. Is this a good way to do it or is there a more efficient method?

```java
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < col.length(); j++) {
   if (charArray[i][j] != '\0') {
     text.append(charArray[i][j]);
   }
 }
this.newText = text.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to travel the entire 2D array to find out the empty element.

For traveling a 2D A[m][n] array, the time complexity (best) is O(m*n), which you're using so there isn't any other method that will reduce the time complexity.

There is a difference between '\0' and ' '. `\0' is for null and ' ' is for empty char.
Your use case needs to omit empty char, so use ' '

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < col.length(); j++) {
   if (charArray[i][j] != '') {
     text.append(charArray[i][j]);
   }
 }
this.newText = text.toString();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I would also like to know if the best way to avoid appending an empty index to the String is by using this piece of code: if (charArray[i][j] != '\0') {
     text.append(charArray[i][j]);

Comment: '\0' represents a null value. There is a difference between an empty char and null.
So, if you want to omit empty value, use `if(charArray[i][j] != '') text.append(charArray[i][j]);`. This will not append the characters in text variable.

'\0' is generally used to find the end of the character, i.e null, not the empty char.

Answer (score 0):

This would iterate all rows and columns of charArray test value and allows for arrays of different lengths:

```
char[][]charArray = new char[][] { new char[] {65, '\0', 66 }
                                 , new char[] {68,69, 70, '\0', 71 }};


StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    char[] theRow = charArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < theRow.length; j++) {
      if (theRow[j] != '\0') {
        text.append(theRow[j]);
      }
    }
}
String s = text.toString();
System.out.println("s.length()="+s.length()+" s="+s);
```

Prints:

```
s.length()=6 s=ABDEFG
```

Note that '' is not a valid character, and '\0' is fine to use.